# express.js get files in FormData as stream

Tags: node.js, express

I use FormData to upload files to express server:

```js
const form = new FormData()
form.append('files', '1.txt,2.txt')
form.append('1.txt', File()) // some file
form.append('2.txt', File())
```

in express:

```js
app.post('/uploadFiles', (req, res, next) => {
const filenames = ??? // ['1.txt', '2.txt']
const streams = ??? // [stream of 1.txt, stream of 2.txt]
})
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you use form data to upload files you find them later in req.files
if your form data is like follows:
[image: form data]

the files will be found in req.files.uploaded and here's a console log of how the data will be

[image]

So in your case, it will be like this

```
  let filenames=[]
  let streams =[]
  let files=req.files.uploaded
  if(Array.isArray(files)){
    for(let file of files){
      filenames.push(file.name)
      streams.push(file.data)
    }

  }else{ 
       filenames.push(file.name) // ['1.txt', '2.txt']
       streams.push(file.data) // [stream of 1.txt, stream of 2.txt]
    
  }
```

Comment: It seems express4.0 removes req.files, and multer middleware save files to disk

Comment: I didn't use multer middleware i just used formdata and found the needed files in req.files, btw I'm using express 4.17

Comment: It is weird, I use express 4.17 too, req.files does not exist. In express doc, multer is recommended

Comment: you need to  add let fileUpload = require('express-fileupload'); and then app.use(fileUpload()); to be able to parse formData without using multer